# Proper nesting of form tags in HTML

Tags: html, forms, indentation

I am replicating a page, and wanted to know if I need to indent the `form` tag, if it is nested inside of a `div` tag. e.g.

```
      <div class="signup-form">
        <form method="post">
          <input type="text" value="First Name">
          <input type="text" value="Last Name">
        </form>
```

Or do I write it without the indentation. e.g.

```
      <div class="signup-form">
      <form method="post">
        <input type="text" value="First Name">
        <input type="text" value="Last Name">
      </form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Sublime2. Writing HTML5 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation in HTML does not matter, it is purely for readability.

For readability, in your example, I would indent.

I would indent because the `form` tag is contained within the `div` tag.

```html
<div class="signup-form">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" value="First Name">
    <input type="text" value="Last Name">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I would indent - to show that the form is contained within the div.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation doesn't affect the way your markup is interpreted. You can follow a standard for readability or your own stylistic preference.

You could also let the IDE format the code for you...

**Visual Studio:**  `ctrl + k, ctrl + d`

**Sublime Text 3:**  Just select all lines `ctrl + a` and then from the menu select Edit → Line → Reindent